# Splitting an array of dynamic length in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

So, I am trying to do a HTML-formular and using the resulting arrays in PHP. Mostly I get what I want, but one thing is tricky and I'm already trying and searching in google for quite a while now.

The short version of my HTML-formular:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="test.php" method="POST"/>
      <table border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span style="font-family:Verdana">&#220;bersicht</span></td>
          <td><textarea name="uebersicht" cols="20" rows="20"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
  $uebersicht = $_POST['uebersicht'];
  $uebersicht = preg_split('/\n/', $uebersicht);

  for ($start=0; $start < count($uebersicht); $start++) {}
?>
```

And here's an example for what the text looks like I want to paste into the HTML-formular:

```
Samperio (59.)
Brosinski (68.)

0:2
beendet

FSV Mainz 05Borussia Dortmund
Coface Arena, 34.000 Zuschauer
Schiedsrichter: Tobias Stieler aus Hamburg
Reus (18., Aubameyang)
Mkhitaryan (82., Aubameyang)
Mkhitaryan (10.)
```

It's highly variable in length, depending on goals and cards. Splitting the array isn't hard, I just do `$uebersicht = preg_split('/\n/', $uebersicht);` as shown in the code.

Now I want to get every player that got a card in this game (every line that ends like  `Samperio (59.)`), the teams (which have to be splitted, too), every goal (like the line `Mkhitaryan (82., Aubameyang)` and every assist (the players in brackets, like `Aubameyang`) into an individual variable. It's important to know in which team the players are (the first lines are players from `FSV Mainz 05`, the last ones players from `Borussia Dortmund`).

The problem here is its variability. Every game looks different, which can be shown in another example:

```
André (39., Brahimi)
Maicon (52., Neves)
Martins Indi (19.)
Marcano (25.)
Pereira (82.)
Imbula (89.)

2:1
beendet

FC PortoFC Chelsea
Estádio do Dragao, 55.000 Zuschauer
Schiedsrichter: Antonio Miguel Mateu Lahoz aus ESP
Willian (45., )
Cahill (41.)
Azpilicueta (66.)
Matic (79.)
```

It's not possible to work with set line numbers. I really don't know how to proceed here and get what I want. Is there any possibility to use trigger, something like "new line" and "(" or ")" in combination for example? Or to search for specific characters and get the line in which they are found?

Or is there any solution without preg_split? Without, the first example looks like this:

```
Samperio (59.) Brosinski (68.) 0:2 beendet FSV Mainz 05Borussia Dortmund Coface Arena, 34.000 Zuschauer Schiedsrichter: Tobias Stieler aus Hamburg Reus (18., Aubameyang) Mkhitaryan (82., Aubameyang) Mkhitaryan (10.)
```

Just one long line - but I guessed it's harder this way?!

Or maybe PHP isn't the right 'language' for this?

Comment: better use an API, like http://www.openligadb.de/Sports

Comment: @baao pretty sure if he had that option he wouldn't be doing this :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, there is no language that is better for this, it can be done with php, javascript, python, whatever you want. Its more about figuring out the process, once you do that, you can code this in any language you want.

Your best bet is to go through line by line, and try and determine, within each line, what is the content, a goal, a goal with assist, penalty, or other metadata.

I would first break it up all into an array by newline which you've already done, then foreach array element, you run it through another regex statement that looks for certain preset patterns. For a goal, it may be some text, followed by an opening and closing bracket with an integer in between.

You will need to learn a litter regex to do this, but its really the only way unless you want to pay stats.com or use another API to get the data already properly formatted.

Also, it may be the first line is always the team, but the # of goals is what makes the rest of the lines dynamic. That way you can find certain metadata a little easier.

So, you can say line 1 is always the team name, line 2 is always the location, then everything else is penalties and goals.

Comment: Well, though it sounds like a huge workaround, since there's no better idea quite now I will try what you suggested.